# Create a RSS page for an Ember.JS blog

Tags: ember.js, rss

I am building a website in Ember.JS, which also has a blog, on its own route:

```
this.resource('blog', {path: '/blog'}, function () {
        this.resource('post', {path: 'post/:post_id'});
        this.resource('tag', {path: 'tag/:tag'});
        this.route('new',    {path: 'post/new'});
        this.route('search', {path: 'post/search'});
```

I have the application.handlebars as the main HTML page template, and blog renders in its {{outlet}}.

Now, I want to create an RSS version of the blog, thus I want to add the following route:

```
        this.resource('rss');
```

I want to reuse the models so I can fetch all posts, use the same controller (which sorts it by date), but using an XML template.

How do I make sure that:

1) The rss template is the only template to render something, i.e., the application template, index template and blog template do not render at all?

2) How do I change headers so I can, for instance, add an eTag?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not extremly familar with Ember but I can only think of one way to achieve this: [data-URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

That means that you'll generate the XML in your controler not but render it in the view. You'll have to output it to a string. Then, you'll base64 encode (`btoa`) this string and do a `window.location = "data:application/xml;base64," + window.btoa(feedAsString);`

This is what we did in [SubToMe](https://www.subtome.com/#/) to export OPML from a single page app (using Angular though) as [you can see here.